# glxgears segmentation fault using open video driver

Tags: 11.04, ati, intel-graphics, fglrx, radeon

I have two videocards Integrated(Intel i3) and Discrete(Mobility Radeon HD5470).

I noticed this problem, after I installed Catalyst 11.5 from AMD site. But there was something I couldn't manage, external monitor worked only in mirror mode with fglrx, and had to revert to open drivers. I removed fglrx with fglrx-uninstall.sh.

Had some problems with booting to Ubuntu, but i successfully managed to start it. Unity works, some games like OpenArena, in low-medium configuration works almost perfect. I assume that open driver is working.

I reenabled vgaswitcheroo, and turned off radeon (because of overheating problems). 
But when i try `glxgears`, it shows me Segmentation Fault.

`dmesg` shows:

```
glxgears[10065]: segfault at 502 ip 00007f486ea4c6d5 sp 00007fffca5567e8 error 4 in libdricore.so[7f486ea1c000+21d000]
```

What can I do now?

PS I think if I install fglrx again, segfault will disappear (IMHO, didn't tested), but external monitor won't work as I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updates from `xorg-edgers` (didn't noticed when exactly) the problem solved itself